# Sharepoint 2013 custom service with separate web.config file?

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, web-config, wcf-binding, sharepoint-2013

I am wondering if its possible to create a separate web.config file for a custom service which references the PSI on SharePoint 2013.

So I have my "service.svc" within a folder in the PSI directory, but I would like to have a separate web.config just for this service. I want to try to consume that service in a more general approach, without going through "ProjectServer.svc" in my client.

So I thought it would be better if I can define the endpoints and the rest of the bindings in that separate web.config file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a separate folder in the mapped PSI folder of IIS. Then inside you can easily install your service when deploying with a separate web.config file.